# Problem showing questions in a quiz made in javascript

Tags: javascript, button, display

I have a form with 5 questions, in which they are displayed one at a time to the user, as in a quiz, that is, the first question appears on the screen, the user answers and goes to the second, and so on.

However, I have a problem with questions 3 and 4, when I don't type anything and press ENTER, question 2 is also appearing on the screen, like the image below:

[![error in questions 3 and 4][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/63pQC.png

I can't show two questions at the same time, just one at a time, and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Here's the code inside the form tag:

```
            <form class="questions_box formulario" action="enviar-landing-page-v3.php" method="post">

                <div id="question-1">
                    <h3>The question is: ... ?</h3>
                    <input type="radio" name="objetivo" id="question-1-answer-a" value=1 required oninput="checkObjective()"> Answer 1.<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="objetivo" id="question-1-answer-b" value=2 oninput="checkObjective()"> Answer 2.<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="objetivo" id="question-1-answer-c" value=3 oninput="checkObjective()"> Answer 3.<br>

                    <div class="text-end mt-3">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function checkObjective() {
                            if (document.getElementsByName('objetivo').value == '') {
                                document.getElementById('submit1').style.display = 'none';
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById('submit1').style.display = 'block';
                            }
                        }
                    </script>

                </div>

                <div id="question-2">

                    <h3>Quantos anos tem seu filho(a)?</h3>

                    <div class="input-formulario">
                        <i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i>
                        <input required type="text" name="idade_aluno_lp" id="idade_aluno_lp" placeholder="Digite a idade do aluno" oninput="checkAge()" maxlength="2" />

                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center mt-3">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-end mt-3">
                        <input type="submit" id="previous2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Pergunta Anterior" style="display: block;" />
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function checkAge() {
                            var countAge = document.getElementById('idade_aluno_lp');
                            countAge.value = countAge.value.replace(/\D/, ''); // Remove caracteres que não sejam números

                            if (countAge.value.length == 0) { // 0 caracteres digitados
                                document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'none';
                            } else {
                                document.getElementById('submit2').style.display = 'block';
                            }
                        }
                    </script>

                </div>

                <div id="question-3">
                    <h3>Qual seu nome?</h3>

                    <div class="input-formulario">
                        <i class="far fa-user"></i>
                        <input required type="text" name="nome_lp" id="nome_lp" placeholder="Digite seu nome" oninput="checkName()">
                        <span id="error-name"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center mt-3">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit3" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center mt-3">
                        <input type="submit" id="previous3" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Pergunta Anterior" style="display: block;" />
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function checkName() {
                            var countName = document.getElementById('nome_lp');
                            var errorName = document.getElementById('error-name')

                            countName.value = countName.value.replace(/[0-9]/g, ''); // Remove numbers
                            if (countName.value.length < 3) { // 0 chars entered
                                errorName.innerHTML = "O nome precisa ter ao menos 3 caracteres."
                                document.getElementById('submit3').style.display = 'none';
                            } else {
                                errorName.innerHTML = "";
                                document.getElementById('submit3').style.display = 'block';
                            }
                        }
                    </script>

                </div>

                <div id="question-4">
                    <h3>Qual seu email?</h3>

                    <div class="input-formulario">
                        <i class="fas fa-at"></i>
                        <input required type="email" name="email_lp" id="email_lp" placeholder="Digite seu email" oninput="checkEmail()">
                        <span id="error-email"></span>

                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center mt-3">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit4" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-end mt-3">
                        <input type="submit" id="previous4" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Pergunta Anterior" style="display: block;" />
                    </div>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function checkEmail() {
                            var email = document.getElementById('email_lp');
                            var errorEmail = document.getElementById('error-email');

                            if (!email.checkValidity()) {
                                errorEmail.innerHTML = "O email deverá seguir o padrão: meuemail@provedor.com";
                                document.getElementById('submit4').style.display = 'none';
                            } else {
                                errorEmail.innerHTML = "";
                                document.getElementById('submit4').style.display = 'block';
                            }
                        }
                    </script>

                </div>

                <div id="question-5">
                    <h3>Qual seu whatsapp?</h3>

                    <div class="input-formulario">
                        <i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i>
                        <input required type="text" name="celular_lp" id="celular_lp" placeholder="Digite seu DDD + celular" maxlength="14" onkeypress="return mascaraCelular(event)" oninput="checkMobile()">
                        <span id="error-mobile"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-end mt-3">
                        <input type="submit" id="submit5" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar Resposta" style="display: none;" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-end mt-3">
                        <input type="submit" id="previous5" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Pergunta Anterior" style="display: block;" />
                    </div>

                </div>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    function checkMobile() {
                        var countMobile = document.getElementById('celular_lp');
                        var errorMobile = document.getElementById('error-mobile');

                        if (countMobile.value.length < 13) {
                            errorMobile.innerHTML = "Além do DDD, o número do celular precisa ter ao menos 8 dígitos";
                            document.getElementById('submit5').style.display = 'none';
                        } else {
                            errorMobile.innerHTML = "";
                            document.getElementById('submit5').style.display = 'block';
                        }
                    }
                </script>

            </form>
```

And the javascript responsible for show/hide the questions:

```
// Variables

var submit1 = document.getElementById('submit1');
var submit2 = document.getElementById('submit2');
var submit3 = document.getElementById('submit3');
var submit4 = document.getElementById('submit4');

var previous2 = document.getElementById('previous2');
var previous3 = document.getElementById('previous3');
var previous4 = document.getElementById('previous4');
var previous5 = document.getElementById('previous5');

// Next question button

submit1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    nextQuestion(2);
    growProgressBar('40%');
})

submit2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    nextQuestion(3);
    growProgressBar('60%');
})

submit3.addEventListener('click', function() {
    nextQuestion(4);
    growProgressBar('80%');
})

submit4.addEventListener('click', function() {
    nextQuestion(5);
    growProgressBar('100%');
})

// grow Progress Bar

function growProgressBar(percentage_width) {
    var bar = document.getElementById('progress_bar');
    bar.style.width = percentage_width;
}

// Shows next question, hides current

function nextQuestion(question_number) {

    var current_question_number = question_number - 1; //question_number is the next question

    var question_number = question_number.toString();
    var current_question_number = current_question_number.toString();

    document.getElementById('question-' + question_number).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('question-' + current_question_number).style.display = 'none';

}

// Previous question button

previous2.addEventListener('click', function() {
    previousQuestion(1);
    shrinkProgressBar('20%');
})

previous3.addEventListener('click', function() {
    previousQuestion(2);
    shrinkProgressBar('40%');
})

previous4.addEventListener('click', function() {
    previousQuestion(3);
    shrinkProgressBar('60%');
})

previous5.addEventListener('click', function() {
    previousQuestion(4);
    shrinkProgressBar('80%');
})

// Shrink Progress Bar

function shrinkProgressBar(percentage_width) {
    var bar = document.getElementById('progress_bar');
    bar.style.width = percentage_width;
}

// Shows previous question, hides current

function previousQuestion(question_number) {

    var current_question_number = question_number + 1;

    var question_number = question_number.toString();
    var current_question_number = current_question_number.toString();

    var el = document.getElementById('question-' + question_number);
    console.log(question_number);
    var el2 = document.getElementById('question-' + current_question_number);

    el.style.display = 'block';
    el2.style.display = 'none';

}
```

**About Carsten Massmann answer:**

The problem with the code was just to change the buttons type="submit" to type="button", and leave only the last button as type="submit", however, I really liked your code, I learned a lot, for example, I had never read about closest method. Could you explain to me how these two lines of code work (what they are for I understand):

```
current = (Q.length + current + inc) % Q.length; // cycle through questions...
```

Above I don't understand why you use the question length.

And on the next line, I don't understand why I use trim():

```
(el.value.trim() ? "block" : "none")
```

I also understand that you cycle between questions, but I need to demarcate the first and last question in the loop, and put something like if Q=0, don't show the "Previous question" button, and if Q=4, that the final button would execute method="POST" and action="next-page". I believe that the "submit" is not being executed because of the loop, but I don't understand why the loop takes precedence over the submit.

Comment: You are making life unnecessarily complicated for yourself: try to avoid working with `id`s as they will require individual addressing. This has lead to similar code being repeated in your case. Putting JavaScript sections in your page body nakes it hard to read and maintain. There is a lot of redundant code and markup. Reducing that will make your page easier to debug and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is still missing your actual validation functions for individual fields but I hope it illustrates the point of how you can avoid unnecessary repetitions in your code and markup. I am using classes to address the various input elements and "delegated event attachment" to combine the click handling for different buttons. For simplicity I allow cycling through the questions. Feel free to change and adapt ...

```js
function changeQ(inc){
 current= (Q.length+current+inc)%Q.length; // cycle through questions ... 
 Q.forEach((q,i)=>q.style.display=(i==current?"":"none"))
}
function showHideOK(el){
 let ok=!!el.value.trim();
 el.closest(".input-formulario").querySelector("input.ok").style.display=
   (ok?"block":"none");
 ans[el.name]=ok;
}

document.querySelectorAll("div.input-formulario").forEach((div,i)=>{div.innerHTML+=`<div class="text-end mt-3"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg back" value="Pergunta Anterior"/></div><div class="text-center mt-3"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ok" value="Próxima Pergunta"/></div>`;
  div.addEventListener("input",ev=>{ let el=ev.target;
   if (el.tagName!=="INPUT") return // only act on input elements ...
   showHideOK(el)
   btn.style.display=Object.values(ans).filter(a=>a).length==Q.length?"":"none";
  });
  div.onclick=ev=>{if (ev.target.type=="submit") {
    ev.preventDefault();
    changeQ( ev.target.classList.contains("back")?-1:1 );
  }}
})
const btn = document.querySelector("button"),
      Q=document.querySelectorAll(".question"),
      ans={};

let current=0;
changeQ(0);
btn.style.display="none";
```

```css
input.ok {display:none}
```

```html
<form class="questions_box formulario" action="enviar-landing-page-v3.php" method="post">
  <div class="question">
    <div class="input-formulario">
      <h3>The question is: ... ?</h3>
      <label><input type="radio" name="objetivo" value=1 required> Answer 1.</label><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="objetivo" value=2> Answer 2.</label><br>
      <label><input type="radio" name="objetivo" value=3> Answer 3.</label><br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <h3>Quantos anos tem seu filho(a)?</h3>
    <div class="input-formulario">
      <input required type="number" name="idade_aluno_lp" placeholder="Digite a idade do aluno" maxlength="2" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <h3>Qual seu nome?</h3>
    <div class="input-formulario">
      <input required type="text" name="nome_lp" placeholder="Digite seu nome"> <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <h3>Qual seu email?</h3>
    <div class="input-formulario">
      <input required type="email" name="email_lp" id="email_lp" placeholder="Digite seu email"> <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="question">
    <h3>Qual seu whatsapp?</h3>
    <div class="input-formulario">
      <input required type="text" name="celular_lp" id="celular_lp" placeholder="Digite seu DDD + celular"
        maxlength="14"> <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><button>Enviar todas as respostas</button>

</form>
```

**Further explanations:**
*Why am I using `Q.length`?*
The expression `current = (Q.length + current + inc)/Q.length` uses Q.length (=total number of questions) to keep `current` *always* within the range of existing question indexes. The term `Q length+...` is necessary to keep values positive for the situation where `current=0` and `inc=-1` and `% Q.length` limits the results from `0` to `Q.length-1`.

*Why do I use `.trim()`?*
This is just a simple way of avoiding that an answer containing only blanks would be accepted as a valid answer.

*Why is there no "submit"?*
I actively disabled the `submit` action by calling `ev.preventDefault()` within my event-handling function.

*How to submit the answers, and when?*
There are many different ways of doing it. My suggestion would be to keep cycling through the questions until all questions are answered in a valid way. At that point an extra button appears that submits all answers at once. I just added that button (`btn`) to the script. It is hidden at first through `btn.style.display="none"` but made visible again on the condition that *all questions* have received an answer:

```
btn.style.display=Object.values(ans).filter(a=>a).length==Q.length?"":"none";
```

The (global) object `ans` is constantly updated in the function `showHideOK()`:

```
let ok=!!el.value.trim();
...
ans[el.name]=ok;
```

Comment: Hi, at the end of my question text, I've added a comment about your answer. Could you please answer my inquiries?

Comment: Just updated and completed my post. Maybe you can check again?